# Volley Server error this site requires java script enabled

Tags: android, android-volley, android-webservice

I am using volley to send web service request and volley response is SERVER ERROR (this site requires java script enabled). I tried POST and GET methods.
After some search on this issue I found these two questions..
[Volley Server error (Requires javascript?) Android Development but there is no answer to solve this issue in 2 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975101/volley-server-error-requires-javascript-android-development)

[Disable Javascript on volley StringRequest but there is no answer to solve this issue in 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376906/disable-javascript-on-volley-stringrequest)

No more questions and solution found. Can anyone tell the exact problem and solution with this issue.
Here is my code

```
public void postRequest(final JSONObject jsonParams,final Handler handler){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConstants.ADMIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                    message.obj = response;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                    message.obj = error.toString();
                    Log.d("error",error.toString());
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Iterator<String> iter = jsonParams.keys();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    String key = iter.next();
                    String value = jsonParams.get(key)+"";
                    params.put(key,value);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Something went wrong!
                    Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                    message.obj = e.getMessage();
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            return headers;
        }
    };

    MyVolley.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
}
```

and web service code is

```
<?php if(true) { echo 'request arrived'; } ?>
```

Comment: What is the site you are sending the request to?

Comment: I am using a free hosting site.. Base.pk

Comment: I think if you hit a webpage that requires javascript it will hit this error, but you shouldn't be making requests like this to sites like that, that is why I was wondering. Are you trying to hit a url that is designed to provide users with a UI or anything?

Comment: no there is no UI in web service code. I I try a simple response and from browser request url works fine..

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice workaround suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684122/4451655) answer.

In Volley, you can override `getHeaders()` method to send the cookie with your HTTP request.

Code :

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Cookie", "__test=YOUR COOKIE HERE; expires=Friday, January 1, 2038 at 5:25:55 AM; path=/");
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same problem , and there is no direct solution for this
problem is:- some servers won't allow these type requests , they allow only web browsers

solution:-

1. Implement a `webview` in your app without any UI (if you are
   expecting Json response).
2. Override `onPageFinished` inside `setWebwiewclient()`.
3. get the page cookie by : `String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);`
4. after getting cookie pass the cookie in header of volley request
   by `key="cookie"`

code reference:-

```
   WebView webViewRequest=new WebView("your app context");

    webViewRequest.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewRequest.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webViewRequest.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webViewRequest.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webViewRequest.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webViewRequest.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webViewRequest.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webViewRequest.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webViewRequest.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webViewRequest.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webViewRequest.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    webViewRequest.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);//here you will get cookie
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished: "+cookies);
            StringRequest Request = new StringRequest(url, new 
     Response.Listener<String>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.toString());
                   // your data from server
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("Cookie", cookies);
                    return map;
                }
            };
            Mysingleton.getMinstance(DashboardActivity.context).addToRequestQue(Request);

        }
    });
    webViewRequest.loadUrl("your url here");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error recently! Your code is totally fine but the problem lies with your web host. (Is it byethost)?
It has a bot detector running which does not let your Android volley request in.Unfortunately this cannot be disabled /turned off.
Try changing your web hosting service.
Hope this helps☺