# PHP REST API not returning response on Android Volley library

Tags: php, android, json, rest, api

I'm using a REST API developed in PHP and slim framework which is hosted on a free host (I am using phpnet.us and byethost, both have same problem). When I use POSTMAN chrome extension to hit the API, the API response is good in JSON format as desirable. However, I'm using Android Volley library to hit the same API, but I'm getting the following response instead of the json format.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
        <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("056f315cfb666fab7e482994a2ae94a6");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://notecloud.phpnet.us/task_manager/v1/login?i=1";</script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a API end issue
This one seems to be the same with "byethost" [Volley Server error this site requires java script enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394310/volley-server-error-this-site-requires-java-script-enabled)